# How to handle returning two objects within switch case statement

Tags: go

I'm writing type assertion helper method which accepts an `interface{}` and returns `string` along with `map[string]interface{}`. I'm returning both objects within a case statement. Why is it asking for return at end of function? Am i missing a break?

```
func typeAssertionHelper(r interface{}) (string, map[string]interface{}) {
    switch g := r.(type) {
    case string:
        return g, nil
    case []interface{}:
        for _, v := range g {
            switch s := v.(type) {
            case string:
                return s, nil
            case map[string]interface{}:
                return "", s
            }
        }
    }
    // missing return end of function
}
```

Comment: Does go need a default clause in your switch statement?

Comment: There is no guarantee you'll reach the return statements. So you need another return statement at the end of the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `r interface{}` that's being passed in does not necessarily match one of the cases that you have in the `switch` block.

Essentailly the `switch` is not exhaustive.

You could extend the `switch` with a default case:

```
switch g := r.(type) {
 case string:
     ...
 case []interface{}:
     ...
 default:
     ...
}
```

Or just return something at the end of the function

`return "", nil`

Comment: yes default won't solve the error. We require to add a value to return or return nil.

Comment: Default _will_ solve the compiler error if it has a `return` statement in it, but since the OP's switch is inside a loop, I doubt that's the desired behavior (since it wouldn't loop).

Comment: Default solves the compiler error if each case (including the default) is guaranteed to reach a return statement or a panic call. Adding a default with return won't guarantee this, as the `case []interface{}` is not guaranteed to return either.

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't noticed that it was a nested switch.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Add a return with nil value at the of the function. Since you are returning from a function you should have a return at the end of function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func Do() string{
    fmt.Print("Go runs on ")
    switch os := runtime.GOOS; os {
    case "darwin":
        return "darwin" 
    case "linux":
        return "linux" 
    default:
        // freebsd, openbsd,
        // plan9, windows...
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s.", os)
    }
    return "OS"
}

func main() {
    value := Do()
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

Or what you can do is have a single return statement in the end of the function. But assign a value in every case which will be returned.

```
func Do() string{
    fmt.Print("Go runs on ")
    var value string
    switch os := runtime.GOOS; os {
    case "darwin":
        value = "darwin" 
    case "linux":
        value = "linux" 
    default:
        // freebsd, openbsd,
        // plan9, windows...
        value = fmt.Sprintf("%s.", os)
    }
    return value
}
```

Comment: The `return "OS"` line in this code is redundant and can never be reached, because of the presence of the default case.  You need _either_ a default return or a final return, not both.  You only need that final return if the default case doesn't have a `return` statement.

Comment: It was just to manage the return from the function we can pass empty string too.